# Does user.name in Git need to match my GitHub username?

Tags: linux, git, github

I am installing Git on an Ubuntu system. I need to set user.name. I already have a GitHub account. If my full name is John Doe, and I've set up my GitHub account with the username "Jon-D", do I need to use that name for the Git user.name or can I (should I) use my full name?

Comment: OK. Thanks. Just wanted to make sure that using different usernames wouldn't have any unexpected, detrimental side effects later on.

Comment: You should make sure that the email address matches.

Comment: To expand on that point, you can have many email addresses configured in your GitHub account. You should make sure that your local setting maches one of those.

Comment: I used the hidden email option, "UserName@users.noreply.github.com" (I used my username, of course). I just wanted to make sure that when I start making commits or what-not, using my full name on my Git setup won't conflict with using a shortened username on GitHub.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, your `user.name` does not matter.

However your `user.email` should match one of the [addresses in your GitHub settings](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/).

`git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL"`

You can also [keep your email private](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private)

Comment: Can you expand why `user.name` doesn't matter while `user.email` does?